# slack disable formating for mobile app

Tags: slack-api, slack

is there any option to disable slack message formating ? I am sending orders from woocomerce to slack. For order ID #119915 slack interprets it as a web color and shows that color. Is there any way how to dissable it?

Answer (score 0):

For that you would need to escape the # symbol, [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86557/how-do-i-escape-formatting-characters-in-slack) answer gives you a couple different ways to do that.